# How do I export a javafx project from NetBeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, javafx

I've already googled for it and then I've read to "Clean and Build" it but somehow when i double-click the jar file in the dist folder it doesn't work, and when i try to run it from NetBeans it doesn't work anymore and i have to make a new project. Am i missing something to make it work? Do I only need the jar file?

Comment: What version of Java are you running? NetBeans?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to get the executable jar file, then do a 'Clean and Build'; But before that make sure your output window is visible. If it is not, press Ctrl+4.
While the 'Clean and Build' process is running, carefully observe the output window for any errors. If there is any, please post it here.
Now check out the jar at dist folder.
Usually, there is a lib folder inside the dist folder which contains additional libraries required for running your application, and in my Netbeans 7.3 it didn't require any extra command line parameters to add the lib folder to the classpath. Instead they have a `JavaFX-Class-Path` parameter in the MANIFEST.MF .  If you are using an older version of Netbeans and don't have those parameters in MANIFEST.MF, you may add it manually by editing the jar file using WinRAR or any other archive manager and add `JavaFX-Class-Path:` followed by names of each jar files in lib folder. Ex: `JavaFX-Class-Path: lib/mylib1.jar lib/mylib2.jar lib/anotherlib.jar`.
Hope this helped. If you have further queries, please comment.. thanks.

Comment: I'm working with Maven projects and I really like the assembly:assembly goal that builds the app with dependencies for me.